# Endpoint authentication in RemixJS

Tags: javascript, remix.run

new to remix and have a question! I'm following a tutorial that suggest the authentication process to be implemented like this:

```js
export function loader({request}){
   await checkAuthentication(request)
}
export function action({request}){
   await checkAuthentication(request)
   await doAuthProtectedJob({})
}
// UI implementation is irrelevant
```

and the server-side:

```js
export async function checkAuthentication(request){
   const isAuth = await checkAuth(request)
   if (!isAuth){
       throw redirect("/login")
   }
   return {}
}
export async function doAuthProtectedJob(data){
   // do database action without checking anything auth related
}
```

and this works fine! the action and the page are protected but since I'm not familiar with RemixJS I was wondering if extra action is required inside the `doAuthProtectedJob` handler.
Is this function exposed somehow to the outside world (something like `http://some-domain.com/some-api/vSomeNumber/doAuthProtectedJob`) that some client can call?
And is it generally a better idea to handle authentication in actions or in handlers? tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe to call the authentication in action and loader.
The Action and Loader are not called on the client side, it runs on the server side. Let's say you request the URL `abc.com/xyz`, so the xyz endpoint will be called and corresponding route page.

User --> Req URL --> The loader will now run on the server side not the client side (you can check the network tab to get the details) --> Now to access the Loaders/Action data you need to call `useLoaderData`/`useActionData` hooks to get their response on the client side, and only the response returned from these is accessible on the client-side.

If you are familiar with `server-side rendering` concept, you will be able to relate better.